# Cannot find name 'SafeHtmlPipe'.Error: Cannot resolve type entity SafeHtmlPipe to symbol (PrimeNg + Angular)

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNg with Angular. Both are on the latest version as shown in the `dependencies` section below:

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.1",
        "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
        "primeng": "^16.0.1",
        "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
    }
```

When I run `ng s` to compile and run the project, I get a compilation error as shown in the following image:

[image]

Comment: It was fixed 3 hours ago: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13218, should be published soon I guess.